# NameError: uninitialized constant Capybara::Webkit.configure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara-webkit

I must not be understanding correctly where to place this method call. I have this `test_helper.rb` file

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest/rails/capybara'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/webkit'

Dir[Rails.root.join('test/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.allow_unknown_urls
end
```

And I get this error when I run `rake test`

NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for Capybara::Webkit:Module
/Users/sameer/code/rails/door_app/test/test_helper.rb:XX:in`'

It seems like I'm doing what's described in the README at the Capybara-webkit Github page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be an issue with `spring` gem version compatibility with rspec version. I updated the gem and it was solved.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, fixed by upgrading capybara-webkit from 1.5.2 to 1.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a gem

```
group :test do
  ...
  gem 'capybara-webkit'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, fixed by restarting spring server `spring stop`. Used capybara-webkit 1.11.1