# capybaraWebKit is unable to visit webpages when running RSpec tests when :js => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

On previous RSpec integration tests where :js => false (i.e., JavaScript was turned off), my tests were running just fine. However, for RSpec tests where :js => true (and therefore needing to use capybara WebKit), I consistently get the following error:

`Unable to load URL: http://my.server:5000/auth/identity because of error loading http://my.server:5000/auth/identity: Unknown error`

Noted this is happening on a line of code that was working just fine when :js => false (it is part of a method that signs in a user, which is required for both sets of integration tests).

**What I have tried:**

- Using ufw (since I am running on Ubuntu), I made sure that port 5000 is open. However, I don't think that this was the problem anyway, since the tests were able to run fine using the same port in other tests when :js => false
- Visiting other pages (e.g., http://my.server:5000/), but the same error message appears.
- I tried using the debugging code that [capybara WebKit documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#configuration) provides:

  `Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.debug = true`

I put it in my spec_helper.rb. But this ends up giving me another error message, namely: `NoMethodError: undefined method configure' for Capybara::Webkit:Module`.

- I tried stopping and restarting spring (using `spring stop` and `spring restart`) following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225895/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-capybarawebkit-configure) instructions. Still nothing is working. (I tried running the tests after both commands, and still got the same error message both times)

**Notes on my configuration:**

- When I received the project, the spec_helper.rb file had `Capybara.server_port = 5000`, and I haven't changed that. This variable is then used in all of the `visit` methods (e.g., `visit "http://my.server:#{Capybara.server_port}/").
- There is no line that has `Capybara.app_host = ______`
- This web app includes three subdomains which I will need to be able to access: `cms.my.server`, `www.my.server`, and `admin.my.server`. (Keep in mind that `my.server` is a stand-in for the actual server name, which I cannot use for legal reasons). All 3 of these are set to resolve to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file.

Also note that my teammate has got the exact same test to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the standard Capybara rspec configuration, when `js: false` is specified (or no `js` metadata is specified) then Capybara will be using the rack_test driver.  The rack_test driver completely ignores all hostnames and ports specified and submits "requests" directly to the rails apps routing handlers.  Because of this if you tell it connect to  `http://my.server:5000` it just goes straight to the routing handlers with a destination of `/` - so the fact that it works when `js: false` is specified does not in any way imply that port 5000 is actually doing anything.

The question to answer is why is Capybara is trying to connect to port 5000.  When testing an app with normal Capybara usage, Capybara will start up the app in a separate thread and bind it to 127.0.0.1 on a random port.  It's highly unlikely the random port would be 5000 and definitely wouldn't be multiple runs in a row.  From here on we're in guessing territory (without seeing your Capybara config) but you probably have specified `Capybara.app_host = 'http://my.server:5000'` which would only work if you combined it `Capybara.server_port = 5000`, thereby forcing Capybara to bind its server on port 5000.  The preferred option would be to do

```
Capybara.app_host = 'http://my.server'
Capybara.always_include_port = true
```

which will let capybara pick a random port, but then add it into every `visit` call made (Note: this all assumes that 'my.server' does resolve to 127.0.0.1 on the machine you're testing on).

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question to give more details on what's going on; sorry for not putting those details sooner. My initial attempts to implement your solution haven't passed, but I will keep on trying. Taking into account the fact that I have 3 subdomains, what should I put instead of `http://my.server` for `Capybara.app_host`?

Comment: @foxeshavedens Setting Capybara.app_host just prevents you from having to specify the full server name for every visit statement - So, if `Capybara.app_host = 'http://admin.my.server'` and `Capybara.always_include_port = true` then `visit '/go_here'` would actually visit 'http://admin.my.server:<the port the server was started on>/go_here'.

Comment: @foxeshavedens And then you'd probably want to add a few helper methods to make it easier to swap between subdomains, etc.  Theres a good article on testing in capybara with subdomains - https://robots.thoughtbot.com/acceptance-tests-with-subdomains

Comment: @foxeshavedens Also - make sure those domain names do actually resolve to 127.0.0.1 and not to ::1 (0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1) if your machine has ip6 enabled since Capybara by default binds only to the ipv4 127.0.0.1 -- since it works on a coworkers machine it should work on yours too

Comment: It ended up being my hosts file. I and actually running on a virtual machine and connecting to the host (where the tests are run in the files are held) via SSH. I had correctly set up my hosts file in the guest but not in the host, which is what got me into trouble. Things again for your help, I think this is the very question I've asked regarding capybara in the last few days that you've answered. Hopefully I don't have too many more...

Comment: @foxeshavedens you're welcome, don't forget to accept answers if they helped so the question gets marked as solved

Comment: Do you know why my test still ran when using rack_test rather than capybara WebKit?

Comment: @foxeshavedens because rack_test doesn't deal with the host name or port at all. It just directly calls the rails action routing, no servers or net connections involved.