# Phusion Passenger is raising an error in a project that doesn't use Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, passenger, capybara-webkit

I am running RSpec integration tests with JavaScript enabled on my rails project and am receiving the following error after using the capybara method `visit` to  go to my sign in page:

`We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly. Information for the administrator of this website: 
The Phusion Passenger application server encountered an error while starting your web application. Because you are running this web application in staging or production mode, the details of the error have been omitted from this web page for security reasons.
    Please read https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/log_file/ to find the details of the error.`

(Note that the previous error message is what appears in the HTML of the page after running `print page.body`, but I removed the HTML tags for ease of reading)

The strangest thing is that we are not using Phusion Passenger in our project (this been confirmed with the project leader). Accordingly, there is no passenger gem in the Gemfile and running `passenger stop` returns: `passenger: command not found`

Any guesses on how this could be?

**My configuration**

- using capybara and capybara WebKit
- my other RSpec tests using capybara work fine, when `:js => false`

Comment: Does your sign_in page make any requests out to 3rd party services?  Or the ip/port you're connecting to isn't actually the one the app you're testing is running on.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thanks again. Ah man... When I was trying out different port configurations because of this issue [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093152/capybarawebkit-is-unable-to-visit-webpages-when-running-rspec-tests-when-js), I forgot to put everything back to its original position, and actually had no port specified at all...ok, time to take a break.

Answer (score 0):

The port that I was connecting to when `visit`ing the sign in page was incorrect, and that somehow connected me to Phusion Passenger.

Credit goes to Thomas Walpole for his help in the comments.